# How to know which variable change to solve the integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am struggling to solve this integral to the method of substitution/replacement method of variables. I know I have to find a *u* which the derivative of u (*u'*) is present in the equation.

But I have trouble finding what will that my variable to replace . I have these two resolutions but of these I would not solve alone and the other I didn't understand anything. 
My question is: Is there a simpler way to solve (even if it is a long resolution) where I can understand every step and make it **more obvious which variable will replace**?

$$
\int \frac{du}{u^2 + a^2}, (a\neq0)
$$

Resolution 1 (I got the same steps but the difficulty is in understanding which replace variable)
$$
\int \frac{du}{u^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a^2}\int\frac{du}{\frac{u^2}{a^2}+ 1}
$$
$$
v = \frac{u}{a} \implies dv = \frac{1}{a}, du =adv
$$
$$
\frac{1}{a^2}\int\frac{adv}{v^2+ 1} = \frac{1}{a}arctan(\frac{u}{a}) + C
$$

Resolution 2: I have no idea what happened to the $+ a^2$ in $(atan\theta)^2 + a^2 = a^2sec^2\theta$ 
$$
\tan^2\theta +1 = sec^2\theta \\
a^2\tan^2\theta + a^2 = a^2\sec^2\theta\\
(a\tan\theta)^2 + a^2 = a^2\sec^2\theta\\
u = atg\theta, du = asec^2\theta d\theta\\
\int\frac{du}{u^2 + a^2} = \int\frac{a\sec^2\theta d\theta}{a^2\sec^2\theta} = \frac{1}{2}\int1d\theta = \frac{1}{a}\arctan(\frac{u}{a}) + C
$$

Comment: suggestion: use backslash before standard functions. It will look a lot better.

Comment: And `\left` and `\right` before parentheses (or any other pair of delimiters) to make them adjust to the size of the content.

Comment: the result is ok

Answer (score 0):

The method you have presented is basically a rehash of the fact that
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$$
Note that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(x/a) = \frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1 + (x/a)^2} = \frac{a}{a^2 + x^2}$$
The above basically proves the result
$$ \frac{1}{a^2 + x^2} = \frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{d}{dx} \arctan(a/x)\right)$$
Now it is "trivial" to see that
$$\int \frac{dx}{a^2 + x^2} = \int \frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{d}{dx} \arctan(a/x)\right) dx = \frac{1}{a} \arctan(x/a) + C, \ C \in \mathbb{R}$$